# Remove / hide Table Head of MDBDatatableV5

Tags: reactjs, datatable

I customized the datatable of MDB v5 and now it requires to remove its table head.

```
 <MDBDataTableV5 hover entriesOptions={[10, 20, 30]} entries={10} pagesAmount={4} data={datatable} materialSearch searching={false} pagingTop responsive sortable />
```

But in documentation and other places like SOF, I didn't find any solution. Also mentioning that I am using it in **ReactJS**. Also checked its Node Module declared class where all the references given, but no header style or header show/hide related things were given.

I also tried by keeping 'label' blank or empty, but it keeps a space for header and cursor still shows a pointer.